# How can we get the quantity in a text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7, python-re

I want to extract the no. 12 in this text. how can we achieve that? Here's the text.

```
 text = "Car Window Clip-on - Buy Here Pay Here (Blue) - Pack of 12"
```

the text is not fix but the `pack of N` is fix

Comment: how about re.match?

Comment: `re.search(r'Pack of (\d+)', text)[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex search!

```
import re
text = "Car Window Clip-on - Buy Here Pay Here (Blue) - Pack of 12"

match = re.search(r"Pack of (\d+)", text)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with lookbehind

```
import re

res = re.search('(?<=Pack of )\d+', text)
if res:
    print(res.group())
```